# compiler.js:1021 Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'UserService' imported by the module 'UserModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm a php programmer and I'm starting at Angular..i'm trying to get a user proprietes  in 
Laravel api but the return is the following error:
`compiler.js:1021 Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'UserService' imported by the module 'UserModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.`

USERCOMPONENT

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { User} from './user';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
@Component({
selector: 'app-user',
templateUrl: './user.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./user.component.css']
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
users: User[]
constructor(private userService: UserService) {
}
ngOnInit() {
this.listarUsuarios();
}
listarUsuarios(): void{
this.userService.listaUsararios().subscribe(users => this.users = users);
}
}
```

USERSERVICE

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { User } from "./user";
const API = 'http://localhost:8000/api/user/users';
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class UserService {
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}
listaUsararios(): Observable<User[]> {
return this.http.get<User[]>(API);
}
}
```

I have tried to import the service here, but I imagine that it being imported into userModule it is not necessary here.
USERMODULE

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';


import { UserComponent} from './user.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    UserComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule

  ],
  exports:[
    UserComponent,
  ]

})

export class UserModule { }
```

USERINTERFACE

```
export interface User {
id: number,
name:string,
email: string,
telefone:string
datascimento: Date,
}
```

Somebody can helpe me?

Comment: The problem seems to be in the UserModule.. cannyou post that one?

Comment: update the question...

Comment: but I imagine that it being imported into userModule, what do you mean by it, You imported it somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You was trying to add userservice into your imports array but it is service it will be in your providers not in imports.
Add your userservice to your module providers like this.

```
exports:[
  UserComponent,
]
providers: [
  UserService
],
```

Comment: you say, something like this?
```javascript
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    UserComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule

  ],
  exports:[
    UserComponent,
  ],
providers: [
  UserService
],

})

export class UserModule { }

```

Comment: yes, and just removed last **,** after providers block.

Comment: ```Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'users' since it isn't a known property of 'app-user'.
1. If 'app-user' is an Angular component and it has 'users' input, then verify that it is part of this module.```

Comment: it is a new error, it is the error from html file where you are using `<app-user></app-user>` selector.